# ¿Cómo mostrar un número con ceros a la izquierda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, string

Tengo una serie de cadenas que contienen números enteros positivos que quiero imprimir haciendo que ocupen el mismo espacio.

Por ejemplo dado:

```
1
23
777
```

Me gustaría que tuvieran ceros a la izquierda y salieran cadenas del tipo:

```
0001
0023
0777
```

[`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) funciona, pero me parece algo engorroso tener que hacer el casting a `ìnt` inicial:

```
>>> print('%04d' % int('23'))
0023
```

¿Existe alguna otra forma que valga tando para Python 2.7 como Python 3.5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

¡Sí! Utiliza `zfill(n)` para hacer que una cadena ocupe `n` posiciones, añadiendo tantos ceros a la izquierda como sea necesario:

```
>>> '23'.zfill(4)
'0023'

>>> str(23).zfill(4)
'0023'
```

De la [documentación en castellano](http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/3/inputoutput.html):

> `str.zfill()`rellena una cadena numérica a la izquierda con ceros. Entiende signos positivos y negativos:

---

Si no se trata de un número, es mejor utilizar [`rjust(n)`](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rjust.html). Lee los comentarios de Patricio Moracho aquí abajo para más detalles, en los que narra el caso siguiente con `--12` que genera un resultado muy raro utilizando `zfill()`:

```
>>> '--12'.zfill(10)
'-000000-12'
>>> '--12'.rjust(10, '0')
'000000--12'
```

Comment: `zfill` es óptimo cuando tenemos seguridad que estamos trabajando con números, pero tiene sus inconvenientes con algunas cadenas, por ejemplo:  `'--12'.zfill(10) --> '-000000-12'`, en esos casos `rjust` tiene un comportamiento más coherente: `'--12'.rjust(10, '0')  --> '000000--12'`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho qué interesante descubrimiento, no conocía `rjust`. Por lo que comentas, parece que `zfill` es un poco "tonto" y cuando ve `-X` coge `X` tal cual y le pone 0s a la izquierda, sin fijarse en cómo está formado ni si en lo que imprime es coherente o no. Gracias

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que `zfill`está orientado al tratamiento de números y trata los signos ` -

Comment: (Va de nuevo) Lo que ocurre es que `zfill`está orientado al tratamiento de números y trata los signos ` -` y '+' de esa forma, cuando hay que hacer un "zero padding" de -23 está bien como trabaja dónde se transforma en -00023, el signo va siempre en la primer posición.  En sí, para "paddear"  números tu solución con `zfill`, para otra cosa, `rjust`.